# WP 8.1 Global Event for Authentication Failed

Tags: authentication, error-handling, win-universal-app

Is there a global event for handling authentication failures in WP 8.1 Univervsal Apps.

Answer (score 0):

No there is not.  There are many ways to 'Authenticate' to different endpoints using different classes, so you need to target each of those scenarios separately.